# Hiveql - Aggregating hourly data to daily

Tags: sql, date, hive, sum, hiveql

I'm very new to Hiveql and would like some help with a very simple issue.

I have a table of hourly data, I've provided a simplified example below:

```
datetimetimezone  ID  value
202007130000+0100 001 2
202007130100+0100 001 3
202007130200+0100 001 4
202007130300+0100 001 1
202007140000+0100 002 3
202007140100+0100 002 7
202007140200+0100 002 9
202007140300+0100 002 2
```

The goal is to create an output where I have datetimetimezone stripped down to "yyyymmdd" format with values being aggregated (SUM) from hourly to daily. So I would end up with a new output like the below:

```
datetimetimezone  ID  value
20200713          001 10
20200714          002 21
```

I know I can use substr(datetimetimezone, 0, 8) to obtain the required date format, however I am unsure on how to aggregate ID values from hourly to daily as the second table above shows. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the following aggregation query:

```
select
    substr(datetimetimezone, 1, 8) yyyymm,
    id,
    sum(value) value
from mytable
group by substr(datetimetimezone, 1, 8), id
```

Note that `substr()` starts at `1` rather than `0`.